# How do you make a leaderboard in python?

Tags: python

I am working on a project for my school and I was wondering if there is a way to make a leaderboard in python? I am fairly new to python and so far, what I have done is get the user's input and store it in a text file. I'm not sure how to continue. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
x = 0

Name = [None]*1000
Class = [None]*1000
Score = [0]*100

# opens the text file called text_file
text_file = open("write.txt","a")

# puts in the values of the highest scores and "saves it" by closing and opening the file
def write_in_file():
    global text_file
    text_file.write(Name[x])
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write(Class[x])
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write(Score[x])
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.close()
    text_file = open("write.txt","a")

# asks for player data and puts highest value in a file
for i in Name:
    Name[x] = input("Name:")
    Class[x] = input("Class:")
    Score[x] = input("Score:")
    write_in_file()
    print(Score)
    x += 1
```

Comment: Could you also post the desired output of this? Should it sort names by score?

Comment: Do you have a specific thing you're trying to do?

Comment: Relax and Let's think through the logics. 
Your final goal is to compare the scores between different users and sort according to their numbers. So,
1. how are you going to insert new users? 
2. how are you going to insert new classes?
3. how are you going to compare users from the same class/different class? 
4. how are you going to rank the users? 
Just relax,think and try your best.

Comment: @MartinGottweis I am hoping to arrange the highest scores with the names and the class at the top, and the lowest scores with the names and the class at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/tutorials.html) for making a leaderboard table. Here is a sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['x','y','z'],
                   'Class':  ['B','A','C'],
                    'Score' : [75,92,56]})
print (df)

Out[3]: 
  Class Name  Score
0     B    x     75
1     A    y     92
2     C    z     56


# changing order of columns
df = df.reindex_axis(['Name','Class','Score'], axis=1)

# appending
df.loc[3] = ['a','A', 96]

print (df)

Out[15]: 
  Name Class  Score
1    y     A     92
3    a     A     96
0    x     B     75
2    z     C     56

# sorting
df = df.sort(['Class', 'Score'], ascending=[1, 0])

print (df)

Out[16]: 
  Name Class  Score
3    a     A     96
1    y     A     92
0    x     B     75
2    z     C     56
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that might help

```
import csv

score=input("whats ya score")
username=input("whats ya name")

with open ("protleader.csv", "a", newline='') as file:
    fields=['score', 'name']
    writer=csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writerow({'score' : score, 'name' : username})

with open ("protleader.csv", "r") as file:
    sortlist=[]
    reader=csv.reader(file)
    for i in reader:
        sortlist.append(i)
for i in range(len(sortlist)):
    if i != 0:
        sortlist[i][0]=int(sortlist[i][int(0)])


print("")

print("Unsorted:")
for i in range(len(sortlist)):
    print(sortlist[i])


for i in range(555):
    for i in range(len(sortlist)-1):
        if i != 0:
            if sortlist[i][0] < sortlist[i+1][0]:
                change=sortlist[i]
                sortlist[i]=sortlist[i+1]
                sortlist[i+1]=change


print("")

print("Sorted and cut:")
for i in range(len(sortlist)-1):
    print(sortlist[i])
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to briefly explain your code and how it will solve OP's problem.